# Do the Barbarian "Call of the Ancients" rune "Together as One" and "Unity" ring stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

*Unity*: "All damage taken is split between wearers of this item"

*Call of the Ancients - Together as One*: "50% of all damage dealt to you is instead redirected to the ancients"

I'm looking to increase my toughness to hit high-end greater rifts. Damage output is definitely there, but survivability is still a major issue. I wonder if those two effects would stack for a 75% damage decrease (50% and then another 50% applied to the remainder, I would assume.)

After attempting a GR55 last night it seemed as if they canceled each other out somehow. (Either that, or I'm far more squishy than I thought at 15.3 million toughness and 663k recovery)

Does anyone know if this works?

**Edit**
I'm using the following build: [Grift 75+ Hota Barb (Group Build)](http://www.diablofans.com/builds/57383-grift-75-hota-barb-group-build)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're assuming is correct. The first 50% damage is split, and then the second 50% is split.

Positives:

- You are taking less damage yourself.

Negatives:

- Assuming it's your follower wearing the Unity ring, unless they themselves have an undying relic, any damage they take is coming your way and by that regard, your Ancients as well.
- If you aren't using a follower and with a group, that damage you're splitting with your party is likely to kill your glass cannons (Wizards and DHs).
- Depending on the rest of your setup, if your Ancients are dying well before the cooldown refreshes, you're spending a lot of time without that extra mitigation.

I'm not sure what build and gear you're using, so I can't give more feedback on that regard, but  looking at the [Barb ladders](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/rankings/era/4/rift-barbarian) and seeing the gear people are in for upper grifts you might need to reevaluate.

Comment: I edited my question to include the build I'm using. I'm not using the recommended solo GR build, so that's definitely a thing, but I thought I would hit that limit in the 60's and not the 50's. My guy is pretty dang well geared. I was able to complete a 55 this morning by playing more carefully. Thanks for the tips, tho!

Comment: @AlbertBori One thing to keep in mind, if you're using a group build, that's what it's oriented towards. This build is oriented more towards having everything grouped up so the entire group besides your zDPS just nuke it all quickly. You won't get the same results you're expecting. Look at the ladders, and then get a feel for what works better for solo conquest.